# making a windows form datagrid view column non editable after inserting data

Tags: c#

i am working on a windows form data-grid. 
there are six column in it.
["A"], ["B"], ["C"], ["D"], ["E"], ["F"]
i need column "C" and "D" to be non editable once any data is inserted in it.
i have tried with ReadOnly but it doesn't solve my problem.
how this can be done?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to make your grid column read only one by one, use:

```
dataGridView1.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true; // for C
dataGridView1.Columns[5].ReadOnly = true; // for D
```